# Are questions about identifying a sports video soundtrack on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I flagged this question (currently 2 upvotes) as off-topic, and my flag was declined: 
[IBU Biathlon theme](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/9188/ibu-biathlon-theme).

I don't understand why is this question on-topic, according to the [tour](https://sports.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [Help Center](https://sports.stackexchange.com/help), I don't see how the composer of the song used as a soundtrack for a sports video is related to sports.

Alternatively, these questions can be asked in [Music Fans SE](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

See the results of [this search for questions containing the word *song*](https://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=Song+is%3Aq).

Broadly speaking, these questions may be of trivial interest to sports fans, who are part of the audience of the site, and in some cases reflect sports in popular culture.

In contrast to autograph identification or memorabilia valuation questions, they may have appeal to a number of people and be useful in the future.

Thus, while other Stack Exchange sites may be more appropriate, there does not seem to be any reason why we should make them explicitly off-topic nor to remove them from the site.

Comment: I added my answer, different than yours.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree to allow these questions for official videos, movies, anthems that are closely related to sports culture.

However, my experience with the Music Fans SE community, where currently all these questions are allowed, says that we should close the door to any other video, unofficial, fan made compilation, YouTube fake trailer etc. as it is almost always unidentifiable copyright free library music.

To me, these questions have no cultural, no sports interest.